# Puppet enterprise installation Issue in CENTOS

Tags: puppet, centos7, puppetmaster

Puppet enterprise Installation issue on CENTOS7(Vmware)

While running the monolithic installation i encountered the following issue " `"Error: Could not start Service[pe-puppetserver]: Execution of '/bin/systemctl start pe-puppetserver' returned 1: Job for pe-puppetserver.service failed. See 'systemctl status pe-puppetserver.service' and 'journalctl -xn' for details. Error: /Stage[main]/Puppetenterprise::Master::Puppetserver/Service[pe-puppetserver]/ensure: change from stopped to running failed: Could not start Service[pe-puppetserver]: Execution of '/bin/systemctl start pe-puppetserver' returned 1: Job for pe-puppetserver.service failed. See 'systemctl status pe-puppetserver.service' and 'journalctl -xn' for details."`

Can you please let me know how to troubleshoot this issue

Comment: A good place to start would be `journalctl -xn` and `systemctl status pe-puppetserver.service`